# How to disable voice message about being unmuted?

Tags: windows, audio, gotomeeting

I'm using the GoToMeeting desktop application for video conferencing. I'm running Windows 10 on a MSI notebook. Every time I'm unmuting myself, I'm getting a voice message that I have been unmuted. Is it possible to disable this voice message? The other users can hear it, as it is played after the microphone has been enabled. The german wording of the message is like: "Die Stummschaltung ist aufgehoben."

I looked in the settings, but couldn't find anything. From searching around I'm not sure if it could be due to a third party app. As the OS has been just reinstalled, it could only be a MSI app.

Comment: Is there anything in *Preferences > Meetings > Usage Tips*?

Comment: Are you using any external hardware to communicate, like a mic or a headset? Or are you using the computers own mic?

Comment: I'm using the laptop's mic and speakers.

Comment: Maybe I should add that all conference call users are muted by default by the moderator and have to unmute themselves to say something.

Comment: Have you looked for a setting as above?

Comment: I will disable "Usage Tips" in the next meeting and check it out. Maybe I'll try disabling all options in that section, although I already tried disabling some.

Comment: Unfortunately, disabling the tips didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Here I post a few options/tests.

1. Some headsets (e.g., some Plantronics) provide those notifications.
   Perhaps the software installed when setting it up takes effect even if you are using the laptop mic/spkr.
   See Plantronics links below.
   **Do you have a Plantronics headset?**
2. For diagnosing purposes (and perhaps it also solves your issue), you could try disabling notifications at the global or app level
   https://www.howtogeek.com/344496/how-to-disable-notifications-on-windows-10/
   **Did you try disabling notifications at the global level? Did those notifications still sound in that case?**
3. As a workaround, you may try locating (I strongly recommend the Swiss army knife [locate32](https://locate32.cogit.net/)) the audio files played with the notifications, and replace them with a "silence audio file".
   **Did you find the sound files associated with the notifications?**
4. As another workaround (I know this does not answer the question) you could use a headset and then others would not be bothered by the notification (only yourself!).
   **Do others in the conversation hear the notification in this case?**
5. Plus, I am not sure this is related
   https://community.logmein.com/t5/GoToMeeting-Discussions/Feature-request-Hide-mute-notifications/td-p/210715.
   At the very least, it suggests it may be useful contacting support, they would possibly be responsive.
   **Did you try contacting support?**

Plantronics:

https://www.plantronics.com/no/no/support/knowledge-base/kb-article-page?lang=en_US&urlName=SF23453&type=How_To__kav

https://commsverse.blog/2017/02/10/skype-for-business-conference-and-mute-off-with-plantronics-and-others-headsets/

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the above helped.

Comment: @MicSim - Please see updated answer with specific issues for you to provide feedback, beyond your general comment.
It would be excellent if you could answer those.

Comment: My general comment was actually targeted at the settings part. Sorry for not being specific. To your questions: 1. No, it's laptop mic/speaker, 2. Yes & yes, 3. Didn't search for them. That would be the hard way to go., 4. Didn't use headset, would probably help, but currently not an option, 5. Didn't try, will maybe do, if no solution here.

Comment: @MicSim - Here's my comments; I look forward to your feedback so you help others help you.
1. I understand your problem happens when using the laptop mic/spk, but do you have a Plantronics or other headset that may have installed a driver or other software? You may check the devices in the Device Manager, or the Control Panel -> Devices and Printers.
2. Ok.
3. I guess yo ushould try that. My candidate directory branches where to look are: `C:\Windows`, `C:\Program Files (x86)`.
4. It would be good if you try once, at least as a diagnostics.
5. Ok.

Comment: No I don't have any headset (and thus software installed). It's a pretty blank Windows 10 install, just 2 weeks old. I'll try looking for the files (albeit I don't know what to exactly search for).

Comment: To look for files, you probably need no more than 15 minutes. Get locate32 (I linked it), it is a portable app so you execute it directly. Update the default database (File -> Update Databases), which indexes the whole disk.
Then search for any file with wav extension, that is the most likely for the notification sounds. Check the directories I posted above.

Comment: Checked for wav, mp3, ogg, but couldn't find any matching file. Even checked the resource DLLs for embedded resources...

Comment: @MicSim - That is very strange, as Windows has quite a few wav files as part of the system. As a checking, please see what you have in C:\Windows\media... perhaps you have to configure locate32.